# Doctrine: How to use "greater than" in select

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

I've a query where I need to find out, if a string contains some substring. And I want to order by the result.

Here is my initial idea:

```
SELECT p, LOCATE(:term, p.name) > 0 inName
FROM xy p
ORDER BY inName, p.name
```

which lead to *Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '>'*. After reading the documentation I understand why.

Is there any simple way, how to use "greater than" in select with Doctrine2?

Comment: I don't think so but from my point of view you could simply remove the comparison because the result isn't more meaningful after checking if the needle exists. I know it doesn't fix the main problem but maybe you can think about the need of this comparison.

Comment: Well, the purpose was to order query results by the result of the comparison. I tried to have the strings including the substring on the end of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there's no way to handle the "greater than" in the way I meant. The only solution I was able to find is to define my own IF function.